# How to import a specific class on a specific POM Dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am enriching a client module which has different WebService calls.

The module implements WS API's and most of the API's share a common EnterpriseMessageHeader object.

The problem I have is experienced during runtime, where a specific method cannot be found. 
when I look at the code and ctrl+hover over EnterpriseMessageHeader object, it shows that it is referencing an incorrect POM dependency. Instead of referencing the 3rd Dependency. It references the first.

Since all the API's share a common groupID... Is there a way to force the reference/import on a lower level than from GroupID?

If I move the dependency to the top of the list. The runtime error goes away and the Ctrl+Hover points to the correct dependency...

This now messes up the other WS implementations I have.

Comment: I realize that my question doesnt clearly explain the issue... I am not really sure how to word the question correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). To ask an on-topic question, please take a look at [asking on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and at [how-to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

So you have two different dependencies that both have a class with the same fully qualified name (The package name and the groupId might coincide, but this is not necessarily be the case - the real problem is that two dependencies, whatever their GAV may be, contain a class with the same name).

This problem is a tough one. Java does not allow you to load both classes and code might break in unexpected ways.

You can try to use the maven shade plugin to rename one of the packages in the dependencies, but you are usually better off trying to avoid one of the two dependencies if possible.